# Get values from many lines till it founds a certain last character

Tags: sql, get

Using sql language, is there any way to get values from many lines till it founds a certain character (in this case, the last '_')?

Ex:

```
1 123fad_gfds_123_123456
2 354_fd_1234_abc_1_ttghknvfgh
```

The desire result should be like this:

```
1 123fad_gfds_123_
2 354_fd_1234_abc_1_
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

**For SQL Server**

`REVERSE` the string and search the position of the last **_** using `CHARINDEX()`, and then just use `SUBSTRING()`

```
declare @var as varchar(30) = '123fad_gfds_123_123456'

select SUBSTRING(@var, 1, LEN(@var) - CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE(@var)) + 1)
```